# js function parameters pass by magic

Tags: javascript, function, logic

I found out a javascript code (that I updated) but there is one part of the code I don't get :/
(full source code here: https://github.com/a-h/ddbimport/tree/working/01-nodeimport )

Part of code i don't get :

```
const batchOf = (size = 25, execute) => {
  const items = [];
  return async (item, last = false) => {
    if (item) {
      items.push(item);
    }
    if (last || items.length === size) {
      await execute(items);
      items.length = 0;
    }
  };
};
```

First, I don't get how the last item can ever be at true? I tried with 5 lines in my CSV and it never does the execute part...

Second, where does javascript get the value of `item` itself? I mean we usually need to declare the `item` or pass it in parameters of the function. Because if when I tried to split the async function itself I need to pass the parameter `item` to my function.

E.g.:

```
const batchOf = (size = 25, execute) => {
    const items = [];
    async function passItem (item, last = false) {
        if (item) {
            items.push(item);
        }
        if (last || items.length === size) {
            await execute(items);
            items.length = 0;
        }
    };
    return passItem(?, ? );  // i should pass some parameters here.. 
};
```

So if someone can help me to fix the issue with the `last` item and also explain to me the magic of javascript because I'm kind of lost for this one.

Sorry if there is a duplicated subject but I didn't know how to search.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Take a look at the return value: `return async (item, last = false) => {...}`. `batchOf` stores a function, which is then called at line 92: `const processor = batchOf(25, async (items) => {...})`.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are first class citizens in javascript, which means they can be stored, passed as parameters, or returned from functions just like regular variables. Here is a detailed overview of this from mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function

To answer your question directly, the 'batchOf' function does not execute the async function in the return statement. When the developer executes the batchOf function, they get back that internal function, which they will call later. In this case they create a processor:

```
const processor = batchOf(25, async (items) => {
    const dynamoItems = toDynamoItems(converters, items);
    await batchWrite({ client, table, dynamoItems });
    count += items.length;
    if (count % 2500 == 0) {
      const seconds = since(start);
      const itemsPerSecond = count / seconds;
      console.log(
        `Inserted ${count} records in ${seconds}s - ${itemsPerSecond} records per second`
      );
    }
  });
```

They pass into the batchOf function details about what they want the second if statement to do, and get back a new function, which they call while reading files:

```
let rowIndex = 0;
  const parser = fastCsv
    .parseFile(fileName, { headers: true, delimiter })
    .on("error", (error) => console.error(error))
    .on("data", async (row) => {
      parser.pause();
      try {
        await processor(row);
        rowIndex++;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Error processing row ${rowIndex}: ${err}`);
      } finally {
        parser.resume();
      }
    })
    .on("end", async (rowCount) => {
      await batch(null, true);
      console.log(`Parsed ${rowCount} rows`);
    });
};
```

Comment: oh thx. I think i got what you mean but then the method `await batch(null, true)` is never defined right ? so how can get the last item(s) then ? because when I try on my local he basically tells me `batch` is not defined :/

Comment: You're right, I don't see 'batch' defined either. It could be a typo and they meant to call 'processor'. It's the working branch of the git repo, not their master release branch, so there is a risk of errors in the code base.

Comment: First thx for your help and explanation. I still have a question though about the `.on("end"` part. For now it send `await processor(null, true)`. But the first params can't be `null`. E.g.: If I got  30 items then 25 items will be processed, then 5 items are lefts and I should go to the `on("end"` part. So how can I get the items left that has not been processed ? I tried to put the `const items = []` to be able to have the items out of the scope but in my solution either I got the full array (30 items). I'm kind of confused..